# Python Variable For Get Request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to move over some API calls I had working over to python from postman, I am having some issues making a variable callable by my next get request. I've found a few things while searching but never found a 100% answer on how to call the environment variable in the get request...is it correct to use the `{{TEST}}` to call that var.  Example below.

```
Test = Myaccoount

Json_Response_Test = requests.get('https://thisisjustatesttoaccessmyaccount/{{Test}}')
```

How can I carry over Test into the request?

Comment: `'https://thisisjustatesttoaccessmyaccount/' + Test`?

Comment: You can use f-string in python >3.6 such as `f'https://thisisjustatesttoaccessmyaccount/{Test}'`?

Comment: In that example, `Test` is not an environment variable, it is just a plain local variable.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn works great, thank you very much. John Gordon, that is true, I will update, the wording from postman confused me with environment variable wording. Thanks all

Comment: `{{name}}` is the syntax used by Postman for its environment variables.  This has nothing to do with python code at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will almost work as you have it if you use the feature of newer version of Python called "format strings".  These are denoted by a `f` at the beginning of the string.  This works like this in such versions of Python:

```
Test = Myaccoount
Json_Response_Test = requests.get(f'https://thisisjustatesttoaccessmyaccount/{Test}')
```

as long as `Myaccoount` is a valid value that can be expanded by Python into the format string.

If you're using an older version of Python, you could do something like this:

```
Test = Myaccoount
Json_Response_Test = requests.get('https://thisisjustatesttoaccessmyaccount/{}'.format(Test))
```

BTW, it's not good form to use uppercase first character names for variables.  The convention is to use uppercase only for class and type names, and use lowercase for variable and field names.

Comment: thank you very much. I will take that into account for variable. Much appreciated.